# Postgresql - Is rolconnlimit upper bounded to max_connections?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-connection

In my postgres database configuration all roles have a "-1" value for the `rolconnlimit` column, which means unlimited connections are allowed for that role. But, there's also a `max_connections` setting with the value 100.
So this means that the sum of all the connections of any user bounded to any role may never surpass 100?

Comment: Yes `-1` means a given role does not have a specific limit. [max_connections](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html)  governs the database server as a whole and serves as the limit for all connections to the server. So a 'unlimited'  role cannot exceed `max_connections` and generally will be less then that due to other roles/processes grabbing connections.

Comment: Although this should be intuitive for developers with a bit of experience, I still think it should be explicit in the official documentation. Do you know if there is such information in the docs? I searched a lot and couldn't find.